# How do I test my $HOME environment variable in a gdb init script?

Tags: gdb, environment-variables

I know that I can say 'set $foo=EXPR' to set a convenience variable to an expression result in gdb, and I can say 'show env HOME' to display my $HOME environment variable, but how the heck to I capture my $HOME value into $foo?

I need to set up a number of variables differently depending on my environment variables, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The cleanest way to do this is to use Python scripting.  In Python you have access to many facilities, including environment variables.

If you don't have Python -- upgrade your gdb!  But if you can't, there is still an approach you can use.  You can use `set logging` or `shell` to print things to a file, then rewrite the file (again using `shell`) to be valid gdb scripts, and finally `source` the resulting file.

Comment: I don't want to have to learn Python just to debug C code, so I guess I'll do it as a Bash script. Not sure why I never thought of that, as I'm already launching the debug session via a script. Thanks!